# I need to refresh the page to login | React and Axios

Tags: reactjs, api, authentication, axios

I have a problem when I want to log in to the login by entering the email and password. What happens is that when I enter with the correct email and correct password, the animation appears but it stays cycled, and if I refresh the page and try again, now it lets me enter into the application

Here's my login form code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { storeToken } from "../utils/authServices";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useLoading } from "../context/hooks/useLoading";
import { LoginForm } from "../components";

export const Login = () => {
  const API_URL = "https://api.app"; //I hide the API for security reasons

  const { run } = useLoading();
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const correoRef = useRef("");
  const passwordRef = useRef("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { value: correo } = correoRef.current;
    const { value: password } = passwordRef.current;

    await axios
      .post(`${API_URL}/api/auth/login/`, {
        correo,
        password,
      })
      .then((response) => {
        storeToken(response.data.token);
        run();
        setTimeout(() => {
          navigate("/nueva-solicitud");
        }, 1000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
        setError(true);
        setErrorMessage(err.response.data.msg);
      });
  };

  return (
    <LoginForm
      correoRef={correoRef}
      passwordRef={passwordRef}
      handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      error={error}
      errorMessage={errorMessage}
    />
  );
};
```

```
    import { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from "react";

const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  alerts: [],
};

const reducers = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "LOADING_RUN":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case "LOADING_STOP":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
      };
    default:
      return { ...state };
  }
};

const AppContext = createContext();

const AppContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducers, initialState);

  return <AppContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }} {...props} />;
};

const useAppContext = () => useContext(AppContext);

export { AppContextProvider, useAppContext };
```

```
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useAppContext } from "../AppContext";

export const useLoading = () => {
  const { dispatch } = useAppContext();

  const loading = useMemo(
    () => ({
      run: () => dispatch({ type: "LOADING_RUN" }),
      stop: () => dispatch({ type: "LOADING_STOP" }),
    }),
    [dispatch]
  );

  return loading;
};
```

```
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

export const storeToken = (token) => {
  localStorage.setItem("token", token);
};

export const getToken = (decode = false) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (decode) {
    const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
    return decoded;
  }
  return token;
};

export const logout = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem("token");
};
```

How can I log in without refreshing the page?

Comment: Does that `run` function ever stop? I think you might forget to clear the loading animation.

Comment: Please show what's inside `../context/hooks/useLoading` --- and this is a paradigm to avoid: *setTimeout(() => { navigate("/nueva-solicitud"); }, 1000);* - just use navigate directly. If you have to use a setTimeout to make it work it's a hack for something that should be refactored.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu I just put the code there:)

Comment: Great. Can you also lastly add `../utils/authServices`?

Answer (score 0):

There's *two* problems here. One is you're using `await` with a `.then` .`catch` block. Pick one or the other. You're also never calling the `stop()` dispatch when your `async` call is complete which appears to be responsible for removing the loader.

Instead of:

`const { run } = useLoading();`

Use:

`const { run, stop } = useLoading();`

Then change this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  navigate("/nueva-solicitud");
}, 1000);
```

To this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  navigate("/nueva-solicitud");
  stop();
}, 1000);
```

Although I would just recommend writing the entire promise like this:

```
try {
  run();
  const response = await axios
    .post(`${API_URL}/api/auth/login/`, {
      correo,
      password,
    });
  storeToken(response.data.token);
  navigate("/nueva-solicitud");
  stop();
} catch (err) {
  stop();
  console.log(err.response.data);
  setError(true);
  setErrorMessage(err.response.data.msg);
}
```

Comment: I put the authServices code up there, I'm going to try your code

Comment: It doesn't work as I expected:( maybe this can help, I saw the token value in local storage and if go to another route with the token there I can go to the other page. I mean, when a press "Siguiente" the token post it into the local storage

Comment: Thank you for providing more code. You tried the stop() after your `navigate()`? Or the try/catch block example? If the latter, drop the async off storeToken (if you used that) since it's not a promise. Also, what do your routes look like, or whatever is handling your logic that hits `getToken()`? Something must watch for your token to be set in `localStorage`, then bring it into `React state` --- Try to list the files that reference `getToken()`